# running a simulation software on a remote server

Tags: distributed-computing, simulation

Some simulation software packages take so much time and processing power to finish the job. How can I run these kinds of software on a remote server? (e.g. a finite element method software such as [ANSYS](http://www.ansys.com/Products/ANSYS+16.0+Release+Highlights), [CST Studio Suite](https://www.cst.com/Products/CSTS2), [Solidworks](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSolidWorks&ei=CcUPVe2oC8mt7ga_7oDIDA&usg=AFQjCNHd2Ii4RY3ncaYFqcWRLOkaduYVMQ&sig2=jJc9y6PGt7p9SqduFzgMIA), ...)

Should I use the same process of setting a domain and host and CMS which is used for a website? for example if a software runs on Windows, should I have a Windows host and run it on the server as I run it in my computer? (in a GUI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most if not all of the mentioned packages seem designed to run on the desktop. If that is the case, a hosted service is not likely to help. Only if you have a `server` component would a host really help. In that case, the software would be able to unload some of the processing to a server or even a "farm" of servers. This scenario is often found in industrial scale simulation systems and indeed commercial grade 3D rendering systems.

If you have software that works solely on the desktop, although it is possible to host this, for example on the Microsoft Azure platform, the communication to you through the GUI is generally so intense that it would slow to a crawl trying to do it over a network.

I would suggest you contact the vendors of the software to find out their recommendations. If the software doesn't support offloading calculations to a separate server, you will have to upgrade your local workstation.